# Benicio del Toro as Fenster - What Accent is This?

Tags: the-usual-suspects

In The Usual Suspects, Benicio del Toro plays the character of Fenster, who has a very unusual accent.

Is this an accent from anywhere in the world, or is it something del Toro made up for the film?

Answer (score 8):

In a few interviews  Benicio Del Toro decided that he was playing a ["Black Chinese Puerto Rican Jew"](http://www.shortlist.com/entertainment/films/30-unusual-facts-about-the-usual-suspects)

Some of the websites where he describes his choice are blocked (I'm at work)

Comment: I'd noticed that after posting the question, but it sounds to me a little like an description he came up with after the movie...

Comment: Also, it doesn't really sound like any of the named accents, not even close.

Comment: @JamesMcLeod Still that might speak for the fact that he made that accent up, even if he maybe didn't really plan it exactly as a *"Black Chinese Puerto Rican Jew"* and came up with that explanation later on.

Comment: @NapoleonWilson - agreed! I've been thinking that myself.